# How does the IP address lease process work?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

When a Computer-A has just received an IP lease, for example 2 hours.  If it is immediately turned off for about 30 minutes and new devices are connected, can any of these new devices receive the IP leased by Computer-A? If Computer-A is off is  the two-hour lease time is still valid

Comment: A "lease" is basically an agreement between two parties over a given time period. When the DHCP server issues the lease to the client, it agrees that the address will not be used by any other device until that time period has expired. There are no such guaranties beyond that time limit however, so if the client wants to continue to use that address beyond the 2 hour time limit it must initiate a request to "renew" the lease. If no such request is received by the server after the lease has expired, then the server  is free to give that address out to another device.

Answer (score 1):

The lease is reserved for the entire 2 hour period.  None of the newly connected devices can get that reservation until it is released after 2 hours.  This is why in networks with a lot of "churn" using a 2 hour lease is a really good idea, instead of the default 24 hour lease.

Comment: I found an RFC that says the following: "Note that in this case, where the client maintains its network locally the client does not normally forgo the your tenancy
 during a normal shutdown". So is that exactly what you answered, right?!. That speaks in RFC 2131

Comment: The default in Windows Server DHCP is 7 or 8 days, not 24 hours. 2 hours is extreme unless you're in a network that is extremely overprovisioned with thousands of clients. The smaller the lease time, the more broadcast traffic you will have.